# Is there a function to list all SPL Tokens in a Wallet using Rust

Tags: rust, solana, nft

Is there a function which can get a list of all tokens a wallet owns using Rust?

Answer (score 0):

There is an JsonRPC EndPoint on Solana : getTokenAccountsByOwner

Returns all SPL Token accounts by token owner.

https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountsbyowner

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
    "params": [
      "4Qkev8aNZcqFNSRhQzwyLMFSsi94jHqE8WNVTJzTP99F",
      {
        "mint": "3wyAj7Rt1TWVPZVteFJPLa26JmLvdb1CAKEFZm3NY75E"
      },
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

I also think there is a way to make calls to endpoints from smart contracts, you should look around for this

Comment: thanks, I need to look at how to make RPC calls from Rust within rust contract